# how I run node-gyp?

Tags: node.js, node-gyp

I follow this link:http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/Javascript.html#Javascript_running_swig
to make nodejs extension.So I create a folder test which contain example.c

```
    #include <time.h>
 double My_variable = 3.0;

 int fact(int n) {
     if (n <= 1) return 1;
     else return n*fact(n-1);
 }

 int my_mod(int x, int y) {
     return (x%y);
 }

 char *get_time()
 {
     time_t ltime;
     time(&ltime);
     return ctime(&ltime);
 }
```

example.i:

```
 %module example
 %{
 /* Put header files here or function declarations like below */
 extern double My_variable;
 extern int fact(int n);
 extern int my_mod(int x, int y);
 extern char *get_time();
 %}

 extern double My_variable;
 extern int fact(int n);
 extern int my_mod(int x, int y);
 extern char *get_time();
```

binding.gyp:

```
    {
  "targets": [
    {
      "target_name": "example",
      "sources": [ "example.cxx", "example_wrap.cxx" ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I run this command:

```
sudo npm install -g node-gyp
```

Then:

```
swig -javascript -node -c++ example.i
```

then:

```
node-gyp configure
```

when I run node-gyp build I got these errors:

```
    gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@2.0.2
gyp info using node@0.12.7 | linux | ia32
gyp info spawn make
gyp infomake: Entering directory `/home/slim/test/build'
make: *** No rule to make target `Release/obj.target/example/example.o', needed by `Release/obj.target/example.node'.  Stop.
make: Leaving directory `/home/slim/test/build'
 spawn args [ 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ]
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:269:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1074:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-32-generic
gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/bin/node-gyp" "build"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/slim/test
gyp ERR! node -v v0.12.7
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v2.0.2
gyp ERR! not ok
```

I found many posts in this subject but it doesn't work for me,I run npm -g install node-gyp and after I run node-gyp-build but it doesn't work.

Comment: I'm using ubuntu 12.04LTS and I have python v 2.7.3

Comment: So what exactly are you trying to build? What does your `binding.gyp` look like?

Comment: I followed this link http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/Javascript.html#Javascript_running_swig      to make a nodejs extension using swig

Comment: @robertklep:I edited the post .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`binding.gyp` refers to two source files:

```
"sources": [ "example.cxx", "example_wrap.cxx" ]
```

`example_wrap.cxx` is generated by Swig, the other one contains your code. It seems that you have named that file `example.c` instead, so `node-gyp` can't find it. Solution: rename `example.c` to `example.cxx`.

Since you're using Node 0.12, you may run into a bunch of complication errors next. If so, open `example_wrap.cxx` in your editor, search for `SWIG_V8_VERSION` and replace the definition to this:

```
#define SWIG_V8_VERSION 0x032873
```

Instead of Swig, you could look into [`nan`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nan), which is an alternative way of creating Node.js addons. It works well (I have experience with it) and there's quite a lot of example code available ([`node-native-boilerplate`](https://github.com/fcanas/node-native-boilerplate) is a good start). It's also much easier to distribute addons built with `nan` because all dependencies are installed during the regular `npm install` process (whereas with Swig you have to rely on it being installed before the module itself can be installed).

Comment: I just found this after running into those "bunch of complication erros" you mentioned :) As you flagged, using`#define SWIG_V8_VERSION 0x032873` fixes these issues. What is going on here though? Why is it necessary to put this flag here, and is there some way to make it automatic?

Comment: After playing with swig/node.js for a bit, it appears that swig cannot handle C++ functions that return arrays (more precisely: functions that return pointers to arrays). That is, it seems you cannot build a function in C++ that returns something like a JavaScript array and have swig automatically convert it for you.

Comment: @George I believe (can't remember specifically) that setting `SWIG_V8_VERSION` to that particular value makes Swig output code that compiles properly on Node 0.12 (and perhaps later versions, too). Usually, the V8 C++ semantics change between significant Node.js updates (0.10 → 0.12 → 4.x → ...), so the outputted code needs to be adjusted. I don't use Swig so no idea if it can be automated.